# s3cmd: how to use server side encryption?

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-server, s3cmd

I'm trying to encrypt some files on Amazon S3 using server side encryption. According to this link

http://s3tools.org/kb/item9.htm

I should only add this flag

```
--server-side-encryption
```

on the put or sync command I'm trying to run, but when I do that I get a "s3cmd: error: no such option: --server-side-encryption" message.

How do I run this command to use server side encryption?

```
s3cmd put file.zip s3://test/file.zip
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 server 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more recent version of s3cmd than what is in the ubuntu repositories.  Use github.com/s3tools/s3cmd master branch (preferred), or the copy in the Debian experimental repository.

Comment: I ended up using --encrypt instead of --server-side-encryption, but that also worked for me since the version in 14.04 distribution has bugs with --encrypt. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you've upgraded- make sure you don't have any remnants of the old version. I had this issue because I had installed the first package via the system package handler but when I upgraded I had installed via python. This left me with the impression that I had upgraded- but had not removed the old version.

I discovered this because

```
dpkg -l s3*
```

Still lists v 1.1 while

```
pip list | grep s3
```

Shows 1.6.1

I fixed the issue by uninstalling the old package using the system package handler.

```
dpkg -r s3*
```

Then when the cron job ran, it ran the python package version 1.6.1 and no errors occurred.